# How to take derivative in sympy with respect to a vector?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to know if it is possible in `sympy` to take derivatives of polynomials and expressions using vector notation.  For example, if I have an expression as a function of two coordinates, x1 and x2, can I just make one call to `diff(x)`, where `x` is a vector of `x1` and `x2`, or do I need to make two separate `diff` calls to `x1` and `x2`, and stack them in a matrix?

This illustrates what works, versus what I want to work ideally:

```
import sympy
from sympy.matrices import Matrix

# I understand that this is possible: 
x1 = sympy.symbol.symbols('x1')  
x2 = sympy.symbol.symbols('x2')

expr_1 = x1**2+x2
poly_1 = sympy.poly(expr_1, x1, x2)

print Matrix([[poly_1.diff(x1)],[poly_1.diff(x2)]])

# but is something like this also possible?
x1 = sympy.symbol.symbols('x1')  
x2 = sympy.symbol.symbols('x2')
x_vec = Matrix([[x1],[x2]])

expr_1 = x1**2+x2
poly_1 = sympy.poly(expr_1, x1, x2)

# taking derivative with respect to a vector
poly_1.diff(x_vec)

# should ideally return same as first example: 
'''
Matrix([
[Poly(2*x1, x1, x2, domain='ZZ')],
[   Poly(1, x1, x2, domain='ZZ')]])
'''
# but it fails :(
```

Is there a way to take derivatives with respect to vectors in `sympy`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are thinking of the `jacobian`:

```
>>> Matrix([Poly(x**2+y,x,y)]).jacobian([x, y])
Matrix([[Poly(2*x, x, y, domain='ZZ'), Poly(1, x, y, domain='ZZ')]])
```

And that `[x, y]` argument can be `Matrix([x, y])` or its transpose, too.